# C# and DAO. Why RS.Fields("ColName") doesn't work?

Tags: c#, .net, dao

```
    dao.DBEngine DBE;
    dao.Database DB;
    dao.Recordset RS;
    string DBPath;

        DBPath = "C:\\Test\\test.mdb";
        DBE = new dao.DBEngine();
        DB = DBE.OpenDatabase(DBPath, false, false, "");
        RS = DB.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM TEST", dao.RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenSnapshot, 0, dao.LockTypeEnum.dbOptimistic);
        RS.MoveLast(0);
        RS.MoveFirst();
        String Val = RS.Fields("ColName");
```

Last instruction works in VBA or VB.NET I think, why doesn't it work on C# ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try  String Val = RS.Fields["ColName"];  C# uses square brackets to reference collections

Answer (score 3):

Use square brackets, explicitly state the property name which in this case is Value and cast it to a string:

```
string Val = (string)RS.Fields["ColName"].Value;
```